# SQL Server Reverse Running Total

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this table:

```
id  ID  Date    Cumulative
1   x   Jan-10  10
3   x   Feb-10  40
7   x   Apr-10  60
9   x   May-10  100
2   y   Jan-10  20
6   y   Mar-10  40
8   y   Apr-10  60
10  y   May-10  100
```

I need to Reverse the "Cumulative" in MS SQL Server Query to be as the following

```
id  ID  Date    Cumulative  Reversed
1   x   Jan-10  10  10
3   x   Feb-10  40  30
7   x   Apr-10  60  20
9   x   May-10  100 40
2   y   Jan-10  20  20
6   y   Mar-10  40  20
8   y   Apr-10  60  20
10  y   May-10  100 40
```

Note: query is for SQL Server 2012

Comment: What does `Reverse the "cumulative"` mean?

Comment: The opposite of running total instead of having it as an incerement, will be subtracting value from previous record

Answer (score 9):

You can use `lag` to get the value in the previous row and subtract from the current row's value to get the reversed value.

```
select t.*, cumulative - coalesce(lag(cumulative) over(partition by id order by date),0) as reversed
from tablename t
```

From @Gordon Linoff's comment.. you can use `lag(cumulative,1,0)` instead of `coalesce`.

```
select t.*, cumulative-lag(cumulative,1,0) over(partition by id order by date) as reversed
from tablename t
```

Comment: the query gave same result as column "Cumulative" no change happened

Comment: it has to do with 2 columns being `id` in your table example. you should change it appropriately.if your `date` column is a `varchar` you should consider changing the `order by` accordingly or use a different column for ordering.

Comment: It works now, I convert Date column from Nvarchar to Datetime. thanks .

Comment: @vkp . . . FYI:  You can use `lag(cumulative, 1, 0)` instead of `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 1):

For below Sql server 2012 using recursive CTE

```
declare @t table(id int,IDs varchar(20),Dates varchar(20),Cumulative int)
insert into @t values
(1,'x','Jan-10',  10)
,(3,'x','Feb-10',  40)
,(7,'x','Apr-10',  60)
,(9,'x','May-10', 100)
,(2,'y','Jan-10',  20)
,(6,'y','Mar-10',  40)
,(8,'y','Apr-10',  60)
,(10,'y','May-10',100)

;With CTE as
(select *,row_number()over(partition by ids order by id)rn 
from @t
)
,CTE1 as
(select id,ids,dates, Cumulative,rn,Cumulative Reversed 
from cte where rn=1
union all
select c.id,c.ids,c.Dates,c.Cumulative,c.rn 
,c.Cumulative-c1.Cumulative
from cte c
inner join cte c1 on c.ids=c1.ids
where c.rn=c1.rn+1
)
select * from cte1
```